# Auction of mortgaged properties in Monopoly

Tags: monopoly

I have few of my properties mortgaged and I actually want to get rid of them. **Can I auction some of those mortgaged properties to generate more cash??**

I know specifically that the bank has the right to auction my properties if I go bankrupt to the bank.

**But can I of my own free will auction my mortgaged properties in the middle of the game?**

Comment: There is a house rule - no form of trade or deal is allowed between players

Answer (score 4):

You can offer any trades to any players; and there’s no specific rules about the format that these offers take. So you can make offers in such a way that it’s basically an auction. If someone says they are willing to pay $100 for your property, then you can always ask if anyone else is willing to pay more.

So yes, you could auction your properties in this way; but really it’s just a series of offering different trades and trying to get the best deal for them. And it’s possible no one will be willing to trade with you; in which case you are stuck with the properties.
From [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf):

> SELLING PROPERTY... Unimproved properties, railroads and
> utilities (but not buildings) may be sold to any player as a private transaction for any amount the owner can get; however, no property
> can be sold to another player if buildings are standing on any
> properties of that color-group.

Note that the player who received a mortgaged property in a trade/sale must immediately either pay the mortgage price + 10% to unmortgage it, or pay just the 10% and leave it mortgaged, which means they’ll have to pay the extra 10% again if they want to unmortgage it later.

> The player who mortgages property retains possession of it and no other player may secure it by lifting the mortgage from the Bank.
>
> However, the owner may sell this mortgaged property to another player at any agreed price. If you are the new owner, you may lift the mortgage at once if you wish by paying off the mortgage plus 10% interest to the Bank. If the mortgage is not lifted at once, you must pay the Bank 10% interest when you buy the property and if you lift the mortgage later you must pay the Bank an additional 10% interest as well as the amount of the mortgage.

Comment: Actually the thing is we created a house rule that -*no form of deal or trade is allowed between players in the game* and if anyone wants to sell their property they have to put their property card face up and hold an auction and the property will go to the highest bidder. 

So can a player officially hold an auction for a mortgaged property? Because I believe bank reserves the right to auction off a mortgaged property

Comment: The reason why I believe officially I cannot hold an auction for my mortgaged property and only bank can do that is - because bank doesn’t allow you to collect rent on your mortgaged property as well - it is not profitable for the bank to allow the owner to hold an auction just as it is not profitable for the bank to allow rent collection on a mortgaged property - because if the bank is lucky enough and the if the owner goes bankrupt to the bank - the bank will be able to hold an auction on its own and get more cash.

Comment: @RishabhBaid I don't quite understand your comments. If you are playing with house rules, then only your group can decide if something is allowed or not. If you don't allow any trades or sales between players, then this would of course also mean that you don't allow auctions, as an auction is just one form of a trade negotiation. But under the real rules of the game, trades, and therefore auctions, are allowed.

Comment: @Gendolkari so if I am playing under normal rules I am allowed to put my mortgaged property card at the centre of the board and hold an auction? (I don’t want to negotiate with 5-6 people I just want to hold an auction and get done with this mortgaged property)

Comment: @RishabhBaid Yes; that is one of many legal ways to negotiate a trade/sale. An auction is nothing other than a form of negotiation.